# Lucene Wildcard Query - Length of matched string

Tags: lucene.net

I have set up a simple lucene.net index and am testing out a few queries.

I have an index with a field called "Biography" and i am running this query

```
WildcardQuery query = new WildcardQuery(new Term("Biography", "*anag*"));
```

This returns back matches for records with the word Management - which is great

If i search for this...

```
WildcardQuery query = new WildcardQuery(new Term("Biography", "*anagm*"));
```

then i get no results.

Here are the 2 strings i have in the index
"im good at project management"
"im good at programming and project management. i like managing things"

Is there a character limit to wildcard searching?

My usecase will be a free text search box for users - hence im not sure what they may type in and wanting to do a wildcard

Answer (score 0):

The partial word "anagm" does not occur in either of your two sentences so returning 0 results should be the expected behavior:

> "im good at project management"
> "im good at programming and project management. i like managing things"

Which sentence did you think would match? and Why?

Lucene is more often used to match words or more specifically tokens from the original sentences.  Doing wildcard matches with Lucene (as one might do with Sql) is quite a bit less common since leading with a wild card is not performant (just as it is not with sql either).